# Unable to duplicate site in multisite wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have a problem in duplicating site in multisite wordpress. When I set up the values needed in duplicating the site it gives error.

"Missing or invalid log directory path"

Comment: This looks like a support request for a plugin for duplicating sites. So here is not the place to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you done, the following code does the check:

https://github.com/wp-plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/blob/7fe14a580a41456c59b7d1dcc3440fdb227ae608/include/admin.php#L333

```
if(isset($data['log']) && $data['log']=='yes' && (!isset($data['log-path']) || $data['log-path'] == "" || !MUCD_Functions::valid_path($data['log-path']) ) ) {
    $error[] = new WP_Error( 'mucd_error', MUCD_NETWORK_PAGE_DUPLICATE_VIEW_LOG_PATH_EMPTY );
}
```

So it will fail if:

- Log is enabled but log-path is empty.
- Log is enabled but log-path is not a valid path.

So depending on which is true, your error lies there.

Comment: It works now, just untick the check box in advance option when duplicating site, and it  work. But thanks for your help.